# SAP HANA: Create a join with a max on date

Tags: hana

I am busy with a SAP HANA development but ran into an issue with currency conversion.

On the left of a join, I have a projection with the Sales Order Number, Customer Requested Delivery Date and order value in Document Currency (from VBAK/VBAP).  On the right of the join, I have a projection containing the TCURR table (from SAP), filtered on MAER (monthly average exchange rate) and the "from currency" joined to document currency from the Sales Order.  I need to convert the value in document currency say to EUR but must select the latest exchange rate available in TCURR.   How do I do the join? So effectively, I need to join the date from the Sales Order to max( Exchange Rate Date) but must be less than or equal to the Sales Order date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please check following HANA db SQLScript

I used [multiple SQL CTE expressions on HANA SQLScript](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/sql-multiple-cte-syntax-sql-cte-example-in-sql-server-2008.aspx) to get the most recent entry for each currency conversion to EUR 
And then join this CTE tables (last one CTE3) to VBAK table

I actually did not do the amount convertion using the currency rate, I think you can handle it using multiplication or division, etc on the SELECT list

```
with cte as (
    select 
        to_date( to_nvarchar(99999999 - gdatu) ) gdate,
        * 
    from "SAPS4S".TCURR
    where tcurr = 'EUR'
), cte2 as (
    select 
        row_number() over (partition by fcurr, YEAR(gdate), MONTH(gdate) order by gdate desc) as rn,
         YEAR(gdate) as gdate_year, 
         MONTH(gdate) as gdate_month,
        * 
    from cte
), cte3 as (
    select * from cte2 where rn = 1
)
select 
    vbeln,
    erdat,
    netwr,
    waerk,
    cte3.* 
from "SAPS4S".VBAK as vbak
left join cte3
    on 
        vbak.waerk = cte3.fcurr and
        YEAR(vbak.erdat) = cte3.gdate_year and
        MONTH(vbak.erdat) = cte3.gdate_month;
```

Hello Ernie,
According to your second comment, I changed the SQLScript query a bit as follows

```
with cte as (
    select 
        to_date( to_nvarchar(99999999 - gdatu) ) gdate,
        * 
    from "SAPABAP1".TCURR
    where tcurr = 'EUR'
), cte2 as (
select 
    vbeln,
    erdat,
    netwr,
    waerk,
    sum(1) over (partition by vbeln order by gdate desc rows unbounded preceding) as rownum,
    cte.*
from "SAPABAP1".VBAK as vbak
left join cte
    on 
        vbak.waerk = cte.fcurr and
        vbak.erdat >= cte.gdate
)
select *
from cte2 
where ifnull(rownum,1) = 1
```

I'll be happy if it works on your database and get your feedback

There are NULL records coming from TCURR table because there is no currency rate entry or the document currency is already defined as EUR (actually the rates should be then equal to 1)

Comment: Good day Eralper!  Thank you so much - it worked 100%.  Wow!!  Much appreciated.  I will now customize for my use but the principle is sound!

Comment: Good afternoon Eralper.  I tried your code in both HANA and SQL and although it works, it does not solve my issue 100%.  The real issue is to return the currency rate equal or smaller to the SO date (so a exchange rate as close as possible but smaller to the SO date).  But thanks - your code give me some direction.

Comment: Hi Ernie, I added a second query, could you please check it too

Comment: You are a GENIUS of NOTE!  This works 100%. Thank you Eralper.  Now I need to wrap my mind around the code to try and understand it.

Comment: Thanks for good feedback :) Could you please mark the solution as useful then ?

Comment: Your posted solution is HANA SQL not SQL Script.

Comment: Hello Lars, I thought the general name for SQL coding on HANA database is known as SQLScript just like T-SQL for SQL Server and PL/SQL for Oracle database. I appretiate your attribute for SAP HANA topics and I personally follow you in the community. I'ld very happy, if you could provide me a guide that is easily understandable about SQLs :) in SAP... Thanks in advance.